# AWS .NET SDK use profile with MFA to access to Secrets Manager (The MfaSerialNumber has been set but the MfaTokenCodeCallback hasn't)

Tags: .net, amazon-web-services, multi-factor-authentication, aws-sdk-net

I'm trying to use AWS Secrets Manager from ASP.NET Core app. I use [AWSSecretsManagerConfigurationExtensions](https://github.com/Kralizek/AWSSecretsManagerConfigurationExtensions) (but this actually doesn't matter).

The code is below. The problem is, my profile has an MFA set up (i.e. there's `mfa_serial` in my `.aws/credentials` file.
So when the code below runs, I get the exception:

```
Amazon.Runtime.AmazonClientException: Error calling AssumeRole for role arn:aws:iam::***:role/Admin
 ---> System.InvalidOperationException: The MfaSerialNumber has been set but the MfaTokenCodeCallback hasn't.  MfaTokenCodeCallback is required in order to determine the MfaTokenCode when MfaSerialNumber is set.
```

I guess, that's expected that it's asking for MfaToken, but where should I enter it?

I run it in both Rider and VisualStudio (with `AWS Toolkit` extension installed in both of them), but it didn't help.

Am I doing something wrong/

```cs
var chain = new Amazon.Runtime.CredentialManagement.CredentialProfileStoreChain();
if (chain.TryGetProfile("PROFILE_NAME", out var profile))
{
    var credentials = profile.GetAWSCredentials(profile.CredentialProfileStore);

    builder.Configuration.AddSecretsManager(credentials, profile.Region);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems, that one have to manually assign the `MfaTokenCodeCallback` and request the MFA there.

So, continuing from the code above:

```cs
var credentials = profile.GetAWSCredentials(profile.CredentialProfileStore);
if (credentials is AssumeRoleAWSCredentials assumeRoleAwsCredentials) {
  assumeRoleAwsCredentials.Options.MfaTokenCodeCallback = () =>
    {
      Console.WriteLine(
          $"Please enter MFA code for {assumeRoleAwsCredentials.Options.MfaSerialNumber}:"
        );
      var result = Console.ReadLine();
      return result;
    };
}
```

After that calling `credentials.GetCredentials()` shows the MFA request in console and succeeds if the entered code is correct